# How can I use bootstrap/bootstrap modal js in view without using widget?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii2

Is it possible in yii2 to use bootstrap js (specifically the modal) in a view without using say for example modal widget or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset to dependency so it is now registered within every view. I think i could run into a problem with in being in the footer however as of yet everything works great.

```
public $depends = [
    'yii\web\YiiAsset',
    'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset',
    '\rmrevin\yii\fontawesome\AssetBundle',
];
```